How to handle transactions in parallelFlux?
We have a very processing heavy flux pipeline. To speed it up we are using parallel flux. But now the problem is that everything is waiting behind Database connection and its still slow. The entire pipeline is currently within one big transaction.
How to handle parallelFlux with transactions so that the DB inserts wouldn't block each other too much? Database is Postgres and we are using r2dbc. Or even better, if the different parallel branches would use different connection.
A simplified example
@Transaction
public void someFunc(){
    doSomething()
    .buffer()
    .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
    .parallel(16)
    .concatMap(id -> doSomethingInParralel(id))
    .sequential()
    .collectList();
}

public Object doSomethingInParalel(int id){
  // run some calculation heavy code here
   repository.insertData(some calculated data);
}

Desired result would be that someFunc is in a transaction. doSomethingInParralel should be run in parallel to each other, like 10 in parallel or 100 in parallel, and each of these should have their own Transaction so that they wouldn't block each other when they try to read or write database.
I tries adding Propagation.REQUIRE_NEW to doSomethingInParralel, but the problem is that the first new transaction that is created will suspend the original transaction that someFunc is running with. And since the original gets suspended I can't create more parallel transactions. using Propagation.NESTED is not an option since it uses the same connection as its parent transaction.
How would I go to create parallel transactions with separate connections to the database?

I'm guessing that you are blocking worker threads at your DB-connections. Have you tried to add a scheduler to unload your threads? For example add .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()).

You are using parallel(16) in combination with .concatMap(...). Does this functionally do anything better than specifying max concurrency through flatMap(..., 16) or flatMapSequential(..., 16)?

@ODDminus1 Yeap seems the same.. But no perf improvement. Issue is most likely in the DB connections. Its waiting for some to end to execute another.

It sounds likely that the insert-operations are dependant on eachother somehow. It's hard to tell without more information about what the statements are executing and how. I'm guessing that there is a reason why you can't execute your insert for a bulk of objects instead of doing them one-by-one?

@ODDminus1 There are reads and writes. Reads can retrieve ALOT of data and writes can write ALOT of data. BAsically what the code does for my test case is that it aggregates 4 hash trees in parallel. Each tree has 5000 leaves. And during aggregation there are point where bulk insert is made with some intermediare data. Like 4 bulk inserts at a time or something. A lot of data movement.
